# Rx Android combine multiple calls to the same service in parallel

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have to improve an old service which is making multiple consecutive calls to the same service and merging all the results in a single list.

Imagine we have a list of IDS = [ 1 ,2 3, .. 6]  So I have to call to the same API with each ID (with retrofit and Observables).

For doing this I'd like to use Rx Android but I have doubts about how to merge the results.

```
        Integer[] ids = {1, 2, 3};

        Observable.from(ids)
                .map(id -> mApi.getData(id))
```

Can we do parallel calls and merge the result following the same order?

For improving the time response the idea is to do this in Parallel but I don't know how to be sure the result will be combined following the same order we do the server calls.

I thought to use **concat** (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html)  but it waits the previous observable to wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `concatMapEager` and its variants.

```
Observable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
.concatMapEager(id -> 
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> mApi.getData(id))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.subscribe(...);
```